# best way to iterate and update pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, iteration

hoping from some help. I have a dataframe that starts off with a State & Level columns having values only when the Signal column = True otherwise the values are None and 0.0.  The initial value of State when Signal = True can only be either Neutral or Low which is determined by the value of the Low column (0 = Neutral, 1= Low). 
Temp    Signal  State   Low Mid High    Level
217.46  FALSE   None    1   1   0
217.09  FALSE   None    0   1   0
216.55  FALSE   None    0   0   0
216.66  TRUE    Low     1   0   1   216.49
216.86  FALSE   None    1   0   0
216.94  FALSE   None    1   0   0
216.73  FALSE   None    0   1   0
216.9   FALSE   None    1   0   1
216.5   FALSE   None    0   0   1
216.89  FALSE   None    1   1   1
216.29  FALSE   None    0   1   1
215.69  FALSE   None    0   1   0
214.97  FALSE   None    0   0   0
215.3   TRUE    Neutral 0   0   1   214.97
215.06  FALSE   None    0   0   0
215.21  FALSE   None    1   0   0
214.86  FALSE   None    1   0   0
214.88  FALSE   None    0   1   0
214.85  FALSE   None    0   1   0
215.27  FALSE   None    1   0   0

What i would like to do is iterate through the rows to update the State column based on the previous value of State and the Low, Mid, High values.

If the initial State value = Neutral then it can only change if the current row's Low column value = 1 in which State = 'Low' or if Temp < Level in which State = 'X'.

If initial State value = "Low" then it can only change to "Mid" if the current row Low column value = 0 and the Mid column = 1 otherwise if the current value of Low column = 1 then the value will continue to be 'Low'.  If both Low and Mid column values = 0 then the value of State = 'X'.

The same logic applies to moving from 'Mid' to 'High' State column Value.  "Mid' can change to 'High' only if the current value of the Mid column = 0 and the High column = 1.  If both are = 0 then the value of State = 'X'

X acts as an end of cycle flag.  No further analysis is required until another Signal = True arises.

Below is an example of the expected output.  As you can see you cannot go back in states (i.e. from Mid to Low or High to Mid) only forward and this only when current state column (Low, Mid, High) value moves from 1 to 0 and the next value is equal t0 1.  And you cannot jump multiple states in one iteration (i.e from Low to High).

Temp    Signal  State   Low Mid High    Level
217.46  FALSE   None    1   1   0
217.09  FALSE   None    0   1   0
216.55  FALSE   None    0   0   0
216.66  TRUE    Low     1   0   1   216.49
216.86  FALSE   Low     1   0   0
216.94  FALSE   Low     1   0   0
216.73  FALSE   Mid     0   1   0
216.9   FALSE   High    1   0   1
216.5   FALSE   High    0   0   1
216.89  FALSE   High    1   1   1
216.29  FALSE   High    0   1   1
215.69  FALSE   X       0   1   0
214.97  FALSE   None    0   0   0
215.3   TRUE    Neutral 0   0   1   214.97
215.06  FALSE   Neutral 0   0   0
215.21  FALSE   Low     1   0   0
214.86  FALSE   Low     1   0   0
214.88  FALSE   Mid     0   1   0
214.85  FALSE   Mid     0   1   0
215.27  FALSE   X       1   0   0

So my question is how best to deal with this and I have about 100,000 rows of data to get through.  The index is numbered from 0 onwards.  I can use .iterrows suppose and not even sure it will work since I need to access the previous value of State to determine the current State value. I'm new to pandas and didn't know if it was the best way to go about it.  Speed is a bit of concern for me.

I started wit something like this but its going become some super spaghetti code with a few meatballs in the mix! :)

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if (i>1) and (df.loc[i-1,'State'] == 'Neutral')  and (df.loc[i,'Level']  < df.loc[i,'Temp']):
        if (df.loc[i,'Low']== 0):
            new_State = 'Neutral'
        else:
            new_State = 'Low'
        df.loc[i,'State'] = new_State
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update pandas dataframe as this way.

```
a = 0  
for index, row in df.iterrows():  
  df.iloc[a, df.columns.get_loc('B_lat')] = "Values"  
  a = a + 1
```

**df.loc[]** update particular value. For instance, "**a**" defines number of the row and "**df.columns.get_loc('B_lat')**" defines column. Right hand side value updated at particular cell.

Comment: Is that somehow more efficient than using .iterrows()?